# Dimensional transmutation and the hierarchy Problem

Tags: renormalization, beyond-the-standard-model

In technicolor or composite Higgs models it is the usual folklore that the hierarchy problem is solved by dimensional transmutation.
I do understand that by dimensional transmutation one obtains a scale that is more or less insensitive to the UV physics such that the problem of fine-tuning is solved.

However, I do not understand if and how dimensional transmutation can explain the large hierarchy between the Planck-mass and the electroweak scale (or some nearby compositeness scale). It is usually said that dimensional transmutation generates a scale "out of nothing". If this is true then I do not understand how it can explain a scale hierarchy.

I do also understand that the Planck-scale inherently is a scale at which the RGE flow has to change as quantum gravity corrections set in. In this sense the RGE flow implicitly contains the Planck scale. 
If we now assume that the above "out of nothing"-statement was wrong then I can understand how the electroweak scale can be generated relative to the Planck scale with some exponentially suppressed factor. But this brings another question:  Would there be dimensional transmutation if there was only the SM and no new physics (in particular no quantum gravity)?

Could someone tell me which of the two viewpoints is the correct one?